# JS get a string to go through expressions replacement a few times

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a way to get a text/string through different regular expressions, and different replacement

easily I can do this in php as:

```
$pattern[] = "regex"; $replacement[] = "replace string";
$pattern[] = "regex"; $replacement[] = "replace string";
$pattern[] = "regex"; $replacement[] = "replace string";
$pattern[] = "regex"; $replacement[] = "replace string";

echo preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$string);
```

I am still learning javascript, i figured `.replace()` but is there a way do an array of expressions? it is not technical to repeat `.replace()` over an over. specially if it's a big list of expressions.

Comment: probably you can learn from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions it's a very good article you can start off

Comment: JavaScript does not provide the option to use an array pf expressions with `.replace`. Maybe you could `.join` the array (of patterns) with `|` to create a single regular expression.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Is Felix's answer what you want, or do you want something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

It requires that both arrays have the same number of elements.

```
function REArray(contents,sArray,rArray) {
    if(sArray.length == rArray.length) {
        for(i=0;i<sArray.length;i++) {
            rx_this = new RegExp(sArray[i],"g");
            contents = contents.replace(rx_this,rArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return contents;
}

var sx = ["cat","best","\\d"];
var rx = ["dog","worst","7"];
console.log(REArray("My cat is the best. He is 3.",sx,rx));
```

When storing regexes in variables in javascript, you have to escape the backslashes. (`\w` becomes `\\w`, `\[b\]` becomes `\\[b\\]`, etc). It can get to be quite the headache to read. (matching an escaped slash `\\` looks like `\\\\`).

Some people like to instead use `/` in their regexes and use a replace to convert them to `\\`.

Something like this

```
var rx_this;

function REArray(contents,sArray,rArray) {
    if(sArray.length == rArray.length) {
        for(i=0;i<sArray.length;i++) {
            rx_this = sArray[i].replace(/\//g,"\\");
            rx_this = new RegExp(rx_this,"g");
            contents = contents.replace(rx_this,rArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return contents;
}

var sx = ["cat","best/.","[3]"];
var rx = ["dog","worst","7"];
console.log(REArray("My cat is the best. He is 3.",sx,rx));
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace` runs each pattern independently, so one pattern works on the result of the previous replacement.

```
function emulate_preg_replace(regexes, replacements, text) {
    if (typeof regexes === "string" || typeof regexes.length !== "number") {
        // Single pattern
        regexes = [regexes];
    }
    var count = regexes.length;
    if (typeof replacements === "string" || typeof replacements.length !== "number") {
        // Single replacement
        var singleReplacement = replacements;
        replacements = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            replacements.push(singleReplacement);
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        text = text.replace(regexes[i], replacements[i]);
    }
    return text;
}
```

```
alert(emulate_preg_replace([/c+/g, /b+/g], ["b", "a"], "bbbcccbbb")); // displays "a"
```